# Exclude audio from time remap

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, audio

I am working on a project, I have separate a audio layer and a video layer (with the audio muted) and I have applied time remapping to the video layer. The issue is now that whenever the video slows down or speeds up the audio also slows down and speeds up along with it. I want to know how to keep the audio speed default without the time remap affecting it. [image: Layers Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I would duplicate the layer before applying time remapping (cmd+D).
Then only apply the time remap to one of the two layers.
Switch off the eyeball on the layer for audio (and make sure the loudspeaker icon is still enabled)
Switch off the loudspeaker icon on the layer with the time-remapping applied to it.